# ksar (a sar grapher) development stopped 2013 - no RHEL 7x compatibility - any alternative?

Tags: rhel, osx, statistics, sar, graph

> Ksar is a BSD licensed Java based application to create graph of all
>   parameters from the data collected by Unix sar utilities. Usually Unix
>   sar is part of Unix' sysstat package and run sa1, sa2, sadc through
>   cron to created data files in /var/log/sa/saNN.
>
> Image can be zoomed by dragging mouse on image to pin point problems
>   Results can be exported to PDF or JPEG format

[ksar](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ksar/) was an awesome tool for generating graphs out of sar statistics. Sadly development stopped in 2013. Do you know any user friendly alternative? I know that it's possible to generate graphs with [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info), but requires much more effort.

My desktop OS is macOS 10.11.6

Answer (score 1):

Using a recent sysstat version (eg. 11.4.0), it is now possible to draw graphs using the sadf command that comes along with sar.
sadf can export data collected by sar in SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics) using its switch "-g".
Read more at http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/

Comment: thanks for news. It's released `Monday August 15th, 2016` that will take years for Redhat to include it in RHEL

Answer (score 1):

There is [Performance Co-Pilot (pcp)](http://pcp.io/), which is included in RHEL. It can visualize sar data. It's not quite as straightforward as ksar, but it is more capable.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fork that seems to be maintained.

The latest commit was a month ago. Real features are getting added.

https://github.com/vlsi/ksar